# Holonomy expansion

Tags: differential-topology, holonomy

From my lecture notes of topological quantum field theory we expanded the holonomy

$H_{\gamma}(A)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}e^{iA_{\mu}(x_1)dx_1^{\mu}}...e^{iA_{\nu}(x_{N-1})dx^{\nu}_{N-1}}$

in power expansion of A obtaining

$H_{\gamma}(A)=1+i\int_0^1dsA(s)+i^2\int_0^1ds\int_0^sdtA(t)A(s)+...$

where

$A(s):=A_{\mu}(x(s))\frac{dx^{\mu}(s)}{ds}$

It is not clear to me how is this expansion made. Where could I find some informations about it?

---

EDIT

There's what I pointed out.

We can expand the first expression to:

$H_{\gamma}(A)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(1+\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}iA_{\mu_i}(x_i)dx_i^{\mu_i}+i^2\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=1}^idx_i^{\mu_i}dx_j^{\mu_j}A_{\mu_i}(x_i)A_{\mu_j}(x_j)+...)$

Then, by changing of variable with support [0,1] and using $A(s)$ defined above, we can do a continuum limit obtaining the integrals and so the expression I wanted to prove.

Do you think that this procedure is right?

Comment: As written, it is meaningless. My suggestion is to supplement your lecture notes with a math textbook on Lie groups and bundles.

Comment: Also according to me is meaningless, so i wandered if there are some steps the professor skipped. Maybe he obtained the integral in the first expression by taking the continuum limit  (even if on the contrary he wrote the integral expression of the holonomy as a consequence of the second expression) and than did a functional expansion? Is the second expression a result of a functional expansion in some way? I also have doubt on the extremes of integration